# How to prevent a "space" from searching MySQL database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, search

Currently, when someone just hits the space key and hits enter it will go to the next page but not search anything - I want to prevent the search altogether.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I don't want to prevent spaces from being used (ie: How do I fix this?) - I just dont want spaces themselves to allow a search.

Comment: strip whitespaces?

Comment: show some code - noone can help when you are this vague.

Comment: Uh what? Show us some code, my crystal ball is in the shop for repairs currently.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your query variable in an `empty` condition:

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['searchterm']))
{
   // do search
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to prevent the form from submitting on the client side. I think the OP did bear this in mind because he tagged javascript. Of course to enforce the policy the serverside should check too but it is questionable if the additional checking in cases where it is unnecessary (that should make up 99% of the traffic) outweights the use for cases where it makes seens, also because there is not much harm done.

Comment: Client side validation alone can be side-stepped. You need the backend check as well.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: I edited my comment, of course it can be sidestepped, but is it worth the effort to do this just to pass a " " as search string? If there were security issues then of course the serverside should check too.

Comment: @Nobody: You're right. I just wanted to clarify to a new programmer reading that not to go with client side validation alone.

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript and trim leading spaces in the `submit` (`onsubmit`) event handler:

```
var searchField = document.getElementById('search'); // or whatever the id of the field is
if(searchField.value.replace(/^\s+/, '').length === 0) {
    return false; // or evt.preventDefault().
}
```

It should be okay to rely on client-side validation here because if the user wants to fool the search engine then they won't mind being brought to a blank page. If there's an actual server-side problem in allowing this, then perform the same check server-side:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['search']) || !trim($_REQUEST['search'])) {
    // Don't perform the search
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @AlienWebguy answer you can use JavaScript to do client side validation in order to stop the page from even getting to the back end. Its definitely a good practice to do the validation on the client side *AND* server side.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ALF3P/4/)**

```
form.onsubmit = function(){
    if(input.value.replace(/^\s/,"").length === 0){
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to trim leading and trailing spaces; if a string consists only of spaces then it will be all leading spaces and no trailing spaces.

Comment: Related interesting read - http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

Comment: @gAMBOOKa hah nice link, I'm a huge nerd for this kind of stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Just take the string, trim the initial and final spaces and check the length; if length is 0, don't submit the form.

Comment: This is OK, but you shouldn't rely solely on client-side checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are procecssing it with php on the backend you can just use `trim($input)`, but for a better user experince use javascript. Set a form validator so it won't submit unless there is something other than whitespace.

```
<form onsubmit="return verify()">
    <input id="foo" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" />c
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verify() {
      if (document.getElementById("foo").value.match(/[^\s]/) == null) {
        alert('only whitespace');
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('found substance');
        return true;
      }
    }
</script>
```